Blurry Graphics in PIXI.js
I'm working on a background made in pixi.js that has multiple small circles.
When i tried to run it , it looked fine but when i zoomed in i noticed that its not even circles.
they're squares
image
This is how i generate the dots (circles) :
const dots = [];
let currentXCordinate = 0;
let currentYCordinate = parentContainer.clientHeight;

while (currentYCordinate > 0) {
    while (currentXCordinate < parentContainer.clientWidth) {
        const dot = new Graphics()
            .beginFill(0x848282)
            .drawCircle(0, 0, 1.2)
            .endFill();

        dot.x = currentXCordinate;
        dot.y = currentYCordinate;

        dotsBackgroundApp.stage.addChild(dot);
        dots.push(dot);

        currentXCordinate += 20;
    }

    currentXCordinate = 0;
    currentYCordinate -= 20;
}

So i tried chatgpt and it told me to increase the resolution when we initialize
await dotsBackgroundApp.init({ background: '#000000', resizeTo: parentContainer, resolution: 3 });

but that dosen't work , slows everything down and ruins the scale of the app that i have built so far.
then i tried to make the antialias true
but that didnt work either
const dotsBackgroundApp = new Application({ antialias: true });

I went to the pixijs playground to make a circle and it wasnt crsip either image

If you're drawing circles as pixel graphics, then it's impossible to draw a circle that would look like a circle when it gets small enough. If you were using vectors instead, it'd be a different story. (For instance, you could use instanced geometry with a circle-like geometry shape.)
